# Can't reenable disabled button

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

i have disabled button in html:

```
<button type="button" className="checkout__submit" onClick={clearBasket} disabled>Submit</button>
```

But when i'm trying to enable it again it doesn't work

```
if (inputsArray.every(input => input.value !== '')) {
        button.disabled = false;
    } else {
        button.disabled = true;
    }
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: That should work, maybe the if statement always return false

Comment: If you’re using react you better use state to do that `disabled={isButtonDisabled}`

Comment: When i added console.log in the if statement its getting logged to the console :/

Comment: Please try changing the button disable status using the above comment

Comment: In React you almost never interact directly with elements. Your react state should always be driving the state of the DOM. and the individual elements within it

Comment: Thanks guys, now it started working!